# STM32 HSE VALUE missing binary operator

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I'm working in SW4STM32 on SPL library. My MCU is STM32F407 (discovery board). I have strange error in stm32f4xx.h about HSE.

```
#if !defined  (HSE_VALUE) 
  #define HSE_VALUE    ((uint32_t)8000000) /*!< Value of the External oscillator in Hz */
#endif /* HSE_VALUE */
```

error:

```
missing binary operator before token "8000000"
```

in console:

```
C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/CMSIS/device/stm32f4xx.h:98:32: error: missing binary operator before token "8000000"
   #define HSE_VALUE ((uint32_t)8000000) /*!< Value of the External oscillator in Hz */
                                ^
```

I have also other errors but I surprised why there is something wrong.

console output:

```
16:57:12 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project ex_vendor_dev ****
make -j4 all 
Building file: ../src/board_init_207.c
Building file: ../src/i2c.c
Building file: ../src/i2s.c
Building file: ../src/led.c
Invoking: MCU GCC Compiler
Invoking: MCU GCC Compiler
Invoking: MCU GCC Compiler
C:\Users\Neptun\workspace\ex_vendor_dev\Release
Invoking: MCU GCC Compiler
C:\Users\Neptun\workspace\ex_vendor_dev\Release
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -DSTM32 -DSTM32F4 -DSTM32F407VGTx -DSTM32F407G_DISC1 -DSTM32F40XX -DSTM32F40_41xxx -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER -I"C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/StdPeriph_Driver/inc" -I"C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/inc" -I"C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/CMSIS/device" -I"C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/CMSIS/core" -O3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -c -MMD -MP -MF"src/board_init_207.d" -MT"src/board_init_207.o" -o "src/board_init_207.o" "../src/board_init_207.c"
C:\Users\Neptun\workspace\ex_vendor_dev\Release
C:\Users\Neptun\workspace\ex_vendor_dev\Release
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -DSTM32 -DSTM32F4 -DSTM32F407VGTx -DSTM32F407G_DISC1 -DSTM32F40XX -DSTM32F40_41xxx -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER -I"C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/StdPeriph_Driver/inc" -I"C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/inc" -I"C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/CMSIS/device" -I"C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/CMSIS/core" -O3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -c -MMD -MP -MF"src/i2c.d" -MT"src/i2c.o" -o "src/i2c.o" "../src/i2c.c"
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -DSTM32 -DSTM32F4 -DSTM32F407VGTx -DSTM32F407G_DISC1 -DSTM32F40XX -DSTM32F40_41xxx -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER -I"C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/StdPeriph_Driver/inc" -I"C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/inc" -I"C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/CMSIS/device" -I"C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/CMSIS/core" -O3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -c -MMD -MP -MF"src/i2s.d" -MT"src/i2s.o" -o "src/i2s.o" "../src/i2s.c"
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -DSTM32 -DSTM32F4 -DSTM32F407VGTx -DSTM32F407G_DISC1 -DSTM32F40XX -DSTM32F40_41xxx -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER -I"C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/StdPeriph_Driver/inc" -I"C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/inc" -I"C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/CMSIS/device" -I"C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/CMSIS/core" -O3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -c -MMD -MP -MF"src/led.d" -MT"src/led.o" -o "src/led.o" "../src/led.c"
In file included from C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/StdPeriph_Driver/inc/misc.h:38:0,
                 from C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/inc/board_def.h:4,
                 from ../src/board_init_207.c:2:
C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/CMSIS/device/stm32f4xx.h:98:32: error: missing binary operator before token "8000000"
   #define HSE_VALUE ((uint32_t)8000000) /*!< Value of the External oscillator in Hz */
                                ^
C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/inc/board_def.h:31:5: note: in expansion of macro 'HSE_VALUE'
 #if HSE_VALUE != 8000000
     ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/StdPeriph_Driver/inc/misc.h:38:0,
                 from C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/inc/board_def.h:4,
                 from ../src/i2s.c:1:
C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/CMSIS/device/stm32f4xx.h:98:32: error: missing binary operator before token "8000000"
   #define HSE_VALUE ((uint32_t)8000000) /*!< Value of the External oscillator in Hz */
                                ^
C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/inc/board_def.h:31:5: note: in expansion of macro 'HSE_VALUE'
 #if HSE_VALUE != 8000000
     ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/StdPeriph_Driver/inc/misc.h:38:0,
                 from C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/inc/board_def.h:4,
                 from ../src/i2c.c:1:
C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/CMSIS/device/stm32f4xx.h:98:32: error: missing binary operator before token "8000000"
   #define HSE_VALUE ((uint32_t)8000000) /*!< Value of the External oscillator in Hz */
                                ^
C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/inc/board_def.h:31:5: note: in expansion of macro 'HSE_VALUE'
 #if HSE_VALUE != 8000000
     ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/StdPeriph_Driver/inc/misc.h:38:0,
                 from C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/inc/board_def.h:4,
                 from ../src/led.c:1:
C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/CMSIS/device/stm32f4xx.h:98:32: error: missing binary operator before token "8000000"
   #define HSE_VALUE ((uint32_t)8000000) /*!< Value of the External oscillator in Hz */
                                ^
C:/Users/Neptun/workspace/ex_vendor_dev/inc/board_def.h:31:5: note: in expansion of macro 'HSE_VALUE'
 #if HSE_VALUE != 8000000
     ^~~~~~~~~
src/subdir.mk:87: recipe for target 'src/board_init_207.o' failed
make: *** [src/board_init_207.o] Error 1
src/subdir.mk:87: recipe for target 'src/i2s.o' failed
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
src/subdir.mk:87: recipe for target 'src/i2c.o' failed
make: *** [src/i2s.o] Error 1
make: *** [src/i2c.o] Error 1
make: *** [src/led.o] Error 1
src/subdir.mk:87: recipe for target 'src/led.o' failed
```

Mentioned files in report:
misc.h:38:0

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
```

board_def.h:4

```
#include <misc.h>
```

board_init_207.c:2

```
#include <board_def.h>
```

board_def.h:31:5

```
#if HSE_VALUE != 8000000
  #error STM32F4-Discovery board uses 8 MHz external quarz.
#endif
```

Errors after deleting phrase on board_def.h:
#error Device type is not defined. in file startup_stm32.c:

```
#else
  #error Device type is not defined. 
#endif
```

I delete this and error vanished but another is "#error STM32 device subfamily is unknown or undefined.", it seems there is no defined device.
But in stm32f4xx.h:

```
#if !defined (STM32F4XX) 
  #define STM32F4XX
#endif
```

Comment: Is this all the messages from compiler? `#define` itself shouldn't produce an error, it must be coming from where HSE_VALUE is used.

Comment: I agree. The error message usually contains a detailed report where the macro was used and how it was expanded.

Comment: I'll add console output to my post

Comment: At one time, `HSE_VALUE` was probably defined as `8000000` and could be used both in C and in the preprocessor statement `#if`. Now it has been made type-safe by declaring it as `(uint32_t)8000000` and does no longer work with the preprocessor. Have both `stm32f4xx.h` and `board_dev.h` been generated by SW4STM32, or where do they originate from? Is it reasonable to simply remove the three lines in `board_dev.h`?

Comment: these files are from someone's project. I deleted these lines and compilation moves forward. There was another error "#error Device type is not defined.". I put code about this in my post. after delete lines, another error shows in stm32.h "#error STM32 device subfamily is unknown or undefined." so device is probabbly not defined.

Comment: I use all /inc and /src files from other project and also CMSIS files and StdPeriph_Driver. These files has a couple of years. I don't know anything about it but versions of CMSIS may be different or something.

Answer (score 1):

`error: missing binary operator before token` -
is an error message from preprocessor. The message text is quite confusing and there is messages in gcc mailing list about it.

In your case the reason for this error is a type cast in `#if` statement:

`#if HSE_VALUE != 8000000`

expands to

`#if ((uint32_t)8000000) != 8000000`

Preprocesor just doesn't know what to do with it, casts are compiler's business. So you can remove this conditional expression from `board_def.h` or remove typecast from `stm32f4xx.h`. Newer libraries have equivaled code, defining `HSE_VALUE`, moved to the user-defined sections.

One more solution is to define `HSE_VALUE` in the makefile as 8000000, without cast operator.

Comment: I removed these lines in board_def.h and error about HSE disappears. There are unfortynately many other errors, for example about not defined device - I put in my post.